# Querying a Pivot table in Laravel 4

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, model, relationship

I have a Email model with the table 'messages' that contains all the message data.

I also have a pivot table 'message_users'.

How could I return all the messages that a user is associated with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a simple question of adding the relationship to the Users model as well so now I can call: `$user->emails;` to retrieve the emails associated with that user.